# Unconfirmed transaction. Please help

Tags: transactions, blockchain

Please help. Probably I set fee too small and now I wait 10 hours so far and transaction is not confirmed yet.

Is there anybody who can help speed it up ?

Answer (score 0):

If you had signed it allowing replace by fee you can update it with a higher fee. Another way if you have a change output you can spend the output with a high fee  (called child pays for parent) last but not least you can wait but that does not speed it up. Also you should consider using the lightning network in the future as it improves speed of payments greatly while reducing. Tx fees.

Comment: thank You Sir. The thing is that I did transaction through Bitcoin ATM and there was fee set by default to 4sat /B.

Comment: It seems to me that the first sentence would only apply if the OP is the sending party, and the second if they are receiving.

Comment: Good answer, but you may want to consider adding it to the question I marked this as duplicate of. *"Why isn't my transaction confirming?"* is probably one of the most common questions asked on Bitcoin.SE, and it helps reduce clutter and improve usability to properly mark Qs as duplicate, rather than having good replies scattered amongst many duplicate questions.

Comment: First confirmation after 12 hours... wow that was fast as hell :)  The big lesson is that you have to put more attention to the fee. Better put higher fee and have good sleep than to little and wait so many hours to confirm.  Good tool to watch: https://jochen-hoenicke.de/queue/#1,2h  you can exactly see when your transaction is going to be confirmed depending on fee. And this one is nice: https://blockchair.com/  -  you can speed up transaction as I did but not sure if it was the case which helped. Only between ruffly 1AM and 6AM low transaction fees have chance to be confirmed. PEACE